# Convert hdf5 to netcdf4 in bash, R, python, cdo or NCL?

Tags: python, r, hdf5, cdo-climate, ncl

Is there a quick and simple way to convert HDF5 files to netcdf(4) from the command line in bash?  Alternatively a simple script that handle such a conversion automatically in R, cdo, NCL or python ?

Comment: Not all HDF5 files can be converted to netcdf4; for example, HDF5 variables don't need dimensions, but [netcdf4-python/](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/) says "before any netcdf4 variables can be created the dimensions they use must be created first." However I don't know of a program that converts what it can, nor even of a list of differences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

with netcdf-c library you can:

```
$ nccopy in.h5 out.nc
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily convert hdf5 format data to nedtcdf-4 data by this command which is given below:

```
ncks inputfile_name.h5 outputfile_name.nc
```

Note: this inputfile.h5 data I have got from mosdac website.

Answer (score 1):

NCL's `ncl_convert2nc` function is my go-to for this type of problem: https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Document/Tools/ncl_convert2nc.shtml

Comment: I wonder if these useful aspects of the NCL language will also survive the translation to pyncl ?